# Custom folder icon in lubuntu's PCman File Manager

Tags: 12.04, icons, lubuntu, filemanager, pcmanfm

i just want to ask, if anyone knows how to change icons of programs, folder etc. in PCman FileManager, Nautilus or Dolphin can do this, but PCman not. Thanks for reply
PS: i want to change it separately, not with icon-theme.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a way to use the file manager, but here's your best option.

First, create a directory somewhere to store all of your icons. I will often make a hidden folder in my home directory called `.myfiles`

Next, direct PCManFM to `/usr/share/applications`

[image: applications]

In order to edit the application icon, you will need root access. You can find this in the Tools menu.

[image: root]

After you gain root access, find the application you wish to change. Right-click it and edit the file with Leafpad.

[image: edit]

Finally, search for the line that starts with `Icon=`

[image: icon]

You can change it to the location of your custom icon. If you created the hidden directory mentioned above, the line might look like:

```
Icon=/home/USERNAME/.myfiles/YOURICON.SVG
```

Save the file. You may have to logout or restart. I don't remember. Hope that helps.

Comment: This works to change the icon for a file.desktop to launch programs. Do you know how to do the same for folders? For example, the folders for Documents, Music, Downloads, they have different icons. I'd like to change the ones for the bookmarked folders.